# Why I can't use this way to solve a distribution problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to calculate the number of ways to distribute 11 identical objects into 4 identical boxes, with no boxes to be empty. So, What I am thinking is first deem the boxes to be distinct. Then, I would have the number of ways of $$10 \choose 3$$. After that, converting the distinct boxes into identical boxes, we would have $$\frac{10 \choose 3}{4!}$$. But, the answer seems to be wrong, may I know why.

Comment: Firstly, you want to put one item in each box, so that none are empty. So that leaves 7 identical objects left to distribute in 4 identical boxes. Have you studied combinations with repitition?

Comment: Sure, thank you. I am a bit confusing with the repeatitions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dividing by too large a factor whenever more than one box has the same number of objects.  For instance, suppose the initial distribution is $(3, 3, 3, 2)$.  There are only four distinguishable ways to place this distribution of *identical* objects in four distinct boxes, not $4!$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just list them out with highest box total to lowest (you can assume this because the boxes are identical). This is related to integer partitions, but I don't think you need to get that complicated.

(8,1,1,1)
(7,2,1,1)
(6,3,1,1)
(5,4,1,1)
(4,4,2,1)
(4,3,3,1)
(4,3,2,2)
(3,3,3,2)

So I get 8 possibilities.